# How to make svg path as moveable?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have created an SVG image. You can see it here:

```
jsfiddle.net/o2n56fyb/5/
```

In this SVG image, there is few dot line. You can see it here:

http://creativeartbd.com/demo/blockchain/

Now, I want to make those dot lines as moveable like it's running continuously. Is that possible? If so, can you tell me how?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) and [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) for example like this:

```js
var polygon = document.querySelector("polygon");
var dashoffset = 0;
polygon.style.strokeDashoffset = dashoffset;

function Animate() {
window.requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
dashoffset += 2;  
polygon.style.strokeDashoffset = dashoffset;
}
Animate();
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid #d9d9d9; display:block; margin:0 auto;max-height:100vh}
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
   <polygon points="50,50 200,50 200,200 50 200" 
            style="fill:none;
                   stroke:#000;
                   stroke-width:3;
                   stroke-dasharray: 30,15;"
            ></polygon>
</svg>
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Let me congratulate you on the SVG gold medal!